# Sencha touch lib not working on Chrome 43

Tags: android, webview, sencha-touch

I have built hybrid app with Sencha touch 2.3 and till recent it was working fine but i recently updated the Android System Webview via Play Store (i have moto g running android 5.0.1) and now i am encountering various bugs in UI as follows :

- The selectfield picker does not work correctly now. It behaves randomly. The store bound to it has data but no items are displayed in the picker when it opens. At times items do get displayed but you cannot select the items at bottom because picker always resets the selection to the item at top.
- Few screens show up blank initially when rendered for the first time. As soon as user touches the screen and moves a little bit the whole screen/view becomes visible.

Also there might be other things that might have broken after updating the webview which i might not have discovered but this a big issue as far as developing for android is concerned with sencha touch. The webview updates are now pushed Over the Air and hence many things may break in future.

I also confirmed the above bugs in older versions of android wherein the webview has not been updated and the above bugs do not show up in.

I am thinking of using crosswalk as the solution to the issues with the webview. Anyone with the same issues or any tips regarding a fix ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue with my Sencha Touch app (almost nothing rendered). Here is the workaround I used which seems to work great:

http://trevorbrindle.com/chrome-43-broke-sencha/

Comment: Thanks for this. Have to fix my app now. It is really bad when you open the app and see nothing at all because the scrollable list there isn't rendered correctly :/.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Ian. The link was tremendously helpful and it solved the issue for now. Sencha has not officially released a build with these fixes so the overrides are the only solution right now.

For anyone facing same issues here is one more link from the Sencha Forums where all the issues sencha frameworks are facing with Chrome 43 are stated and solved.

https://www.sencha.com/forum/announcement.php?f=92&a=58

Answer (score 0):

I am also stuck with same issue and i found solution we should not update the chrome. Better download **42.0.2311.152_chrome64_installer** which is offline exe for chrome.

Comment: This may work on your local machine but you don't have any control over what version your users have.